# Find $f'(x)$ given that $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(1 - x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta)d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Find $f'(x)$ given that $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(1 - x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta)\,d\theta$, where $|x| < 1$

Recently I asked a question that involved the theory in dealing with a question like this:

[Find $f'$ for the function $f(x,y) = \int_{a}^{x + y}g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391251/find-f-for-the-function-fx-y-int-ax-yg)

Using what I got from that question I went about solving this expression:
$$\text{Define} \ F(u) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}g(\theta)\,d\theta,\ \text{where}\ g(\theta) = \log(1 - x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta)\ \text{where}\ F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\ \text{Define}\  u(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}, \ \text{where}\ u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

Using the ideas covered previously:

$$(F \circ u)(x) = F(u(x)) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(1 - x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta)\,d\theta $$

THerefore:

$$D(F \circ u)(x) =  DF(u(x)) \cdot Du(x) \\
\text{where}\ DF(u(x)) = \log(1-x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta) \\ \text{and}\ Du(x) = 0 \\ \therefore DF(u(x)) \cdot Du(x) = 0 $$

And I know/feel this is not right. I feel I'm supposed to treat the things within the log function in some way, but according to how I was looking at them in my previous question they are all dummy variables with no importance. Where am I going wrong in my examination of the expression ?

Comment: I'm quite confused by your working. You're defining $u(x)=\pi/2$, a constant? Where did $u$ pop up from in $F(u)$ and what happened to $x$? And doesn't $g(\theta)$ also depend on $x$, so shouldn't it be $g(\theta,x)$?

Comment: I'm thinking of the whole thing in terms of functions. So I did "define" $u(x) = \frac{pi}{2}$ as a constant. If you look at the previous question I asked, I treated $g(\theta)$ as a kind of "dummy" function.....The treatment may not be correct though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful formula which comes to mind, it's called differentiating past the integral. Here it is:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b f(x,t)dx=\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dx,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be constants in terms of $t$ and $x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure we're allowed to use that technique because that involves proving come convergence theorems. Though I am aware of them, this class is a level below "legitimately" being allowed to use that theorem.

Comment: @dc3rd aah, that's a shame. I don't know how else one would do this problem, other than actually evaluating that integral, then taking the derivative, but that would require techniques and functions that are far more advanced.

Comment: Actually the second part of the exercise asks to evaluate the integral.....

Comment: @dc3rd : are you sure you are not allowed to use the result mentioned in the question? If not then your only recourse is to construct a proof of the result in this answer for the specific integral here. Once you get $f'$ you can integrate to get $f$ and the original integral gets evaluated.

Comment: Considering that this is a 2nd yr university course, albeit the advanced section, and having done some higher year courses previous to this one in a different stream, I don't think they would want us to have to prove the convergence theorems especially not yet since this is a first look at multivariate analysis at the 2nd year level. So from that long winded answer perhaps I am able to use the interchanging of derivative and integrand idea. Could you expand on what you mean @ParamanandSingh ?

Comment: @dc3rd: well you use the definition of derivative and prove the result mentioned in this answer, but you do that for the specific integrand $\log(1-x^2\cos^2\theta)$. Btw are you allowed to use interchange of series with integral?

Comment: It's early days in the course, I somewhat know where you're going with the suggestion. Considering that if I wasn't allowed to interchange series with integral that it would be a lot more complicated, I'm going to assume that we are allowed to do it without knowing the reason behind why it's valid to do.

Comment: @dc3rd: then see my answer based on it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another try by evaluating the integral directly. Use the fact that $$\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ to get $$f(x) =-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\theta\,d\theta$$ (here one does use the interchange of integral with infinite series). And then this gets reduced to $$f(x) =-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\dots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\dots (2n)}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$ and then differentiating it we get  $$f'(x) =-\frac{\pi} {x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1\cdot 3\dots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\dots (2n)}x^{2n}=-\frac{\pi} {x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1\right)$$

Comment: This somewhat makes sense to me based on things I've done before. I'll work out the details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah this way is better. (+1)