# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-2x\cos^{2}\theta}{1-x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}d\theta$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-2x\cos^{2}\theta}{1-x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}d\theta$$

THis question arises from an earlier question I was working on which I posted here: [Find $f'(x)$ given that $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(1 - x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta)d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391366/find-fx-given-that-fx-int-0-frac-pi2-log1-x2-cos2-t)

I tried a few different things all to no avail...Which Trig trick am I missing to apply to this question?

Comment: Have you tried the Weierstrass substitution?

Comment: Might be irrelevant but the numerator is the denominator differentiated with respect to $x$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I forgot to change it in the title..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate as follows,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-2x\cos^{2}\theta}{1-x^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}d\theta$$

$$=\frac2x \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1-x^2\cos^2\theta}\right) d\theta $$
$$=\frac2x \left(\frac\pi2 
- \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{d(\tan\theta)}{\tan^2\theta+1-x^2} \right)$$

$$=\frac2x \left(\frac\pi2 
-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tan^{-1} \frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \bigg|_0^{\pi/2}\right)$$

$$=\frac{\pi}x \left(1 -\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$